# how similar is the language used for android SDK to java?

Tags: java, android-studio

is there a point starting with java basisc or should I go for android-based examples and tutorials?

Comment: They are basically the same language. Java

Comment: Android sdk will have android specific APIs that you will have to learn but the language will be in java i.e. you should know java first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android SDK is build in and using Java.

They are for all intents and purposes the same.

However Android is coded using it's own specific library methods and syntax, hence it's a better idea to skip directly to Android. Knowing Java makes it easier but is not a necessity to code in Android.

You will require the JDK since it does need Java to run.

Answer (score 0):

They are basically the same. But, I recommend going with android based examples since android has unique app cycle and app format.